# assembly prints out selectively

Tags: arrays, assembly, printing, mips

I want take  8 inputs and create two 2X2 arrays in assembly. However when i run it it only asks me for a(1,1)a(1,2)a(2,2)b(1,2)b(2,2) and then error. What is wrong?I want to use doubles not integers.That is my code

```
.data

arrA: .space 32
arrB: .space 32
arrC: .space 32

msg1: .asciiz "a(1,1)="
msg2: .asciiz "a(1,2)="
msg3: .asciiz "a(2,1)="
msg4: .asciiz "a(2,2)="
msg5: .asciiz "b(1,1)="
msg6: .asciiz "b(1,2)="
msg7: .asciiz "b(2,1)="
msg8: .asciiz "b(2,2)="


.text
.globl main

main:

la $a0, arrA
la $a1, arrB
la $a2, arrC

#Prints msg1
li $v0, 4
la $a0, msg1
syscall

li $v0, 7
syscall
sdc1 $f0, 0($a0)

#Prints msg2
li $v0, 4
la $a0, msg2
syscall

li $v0, 7
syscall
sdc1 $f0, 8($a0)

#Prints msg3
li $v0, 4
la $a0, msg3
syscall

li $v0, 7
syscall
sdc1 $f0, 16($a0)

#Prints msg4
li $v0, 4
la $a0, msg4
syscall

li $v0, 7
syscall
sdc1 $f0, 24($a0)

#Prints msg5
li $v0, 4
la $a0, msg5
syscall

li $v0, 7
syscall
sdc1 $f0, 0($a1)

#Prints msg6
li $v0, 4
la $a0, msg6
syscall

li $v0, 7
syscall
sdc1 $f0, 8($a1)

#Prints msg7
li $v0, 4
la $a0, msg7
syscall

li $v0, 7
syscall
sdc1 $f0, 16($a1)

#Prints msg8
li $v0, 4
la $a0, msg8
syscall

li $v0, 7
syscall
sdc1 $f0, 24($a0)`
```

Comment: _"and then error"_ **What** error? The simulator would've given you an error message.

Comment: ok no error i fixed that but still the selective printing.. it just prints a(1,1)a(1,2)a(2,2)b(1,2)b(2,2)

Answer (score 2):

For each of the system calls that require integer arguments, you're modifying `$a0`. And once you've done that, `$a0` no longer contains the address of `arrA`. So you end up storing the doubles into the memory where your strings are located.

The easiest solution would be to use another register for the address of `arrA`.

---

And you really ought to simplify this into a loop, since you're just doing the same thing 8 times.

Comment: i changed the registers name to $a3 and now it doesnt even print

Comment: Well, you have to change it in every place where you try to access `arrA`.